# How to install modules in different python installations using pip for Windows

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a standalone executable with PyInstaller. I currently have Python 3.4 which is not supported by PyInstaller. I downloaded Python 2.7 but now I am not able to install PyInstaller with pip. I set the path variable to C:/Python24 but I still get this message when I type `python pip` into the command console.

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python34....

When I use the commands:

```
echo %PATH% 
python pip.py
```

I get the output:

> c:\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;c:\windows\system32;c:\Python34;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC
>
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
>
> Cleaning up...

Comment: @BartoszKP Thanks. Any idea how to use pip with Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install pip for Python 2.7 run the get-pip.py (you can get it [here](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) for example) script using Python 2.7 interpreter:

> > C:\Python27\python.exe get-pip.py
>
> Downloading/unpacking pip
>
> Installing collected packages: pip
>
> Successfully installed pip
>
> Cleaning up...
>
> > C:\Python27\Scripts>c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe
>
> Usage:
>
> pip <command> [options]
>
> [...]

To run scripts from a particular Python distribution go to their directory in the console:

Typically:

> > C:
>
> C:\......\
>
> > cd \Python27\Scripts
>
> C:\Python27\Scripts
>
> > pip or easy_install or whatever

If you want to have it in PATH, then the *Scripts* subdirectory is the one to add, not just Python's root directory. Also be sure to remove any other occurrences of Python paths in this variable (in **both** system and user PATH settings).

Alternatively, you can just download the package directly (e.g. for PyInstaller: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/2.1).

Comment: But these ARE the only occurrences of Python in my PATH: `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;`

Comment: @the_prole what happens when you run `echo %PATH%` in the same console you're running pip?

Comment: I'm not able to redirect command console output to a file for some reason, but the output shows more path variables than I thought I had including old ones like `c:\Python34`

Comment: @the_prole Check both SYSTEM and USER path settings - they are being merged for each process.

Comment: Ok, I used redirect correctly, you can see the output above... I will try to understand you advice. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect! It worked. I just changed `Python34` to `Python27` in the user variables.